# Have begun or begins

Tags: grammar

Hello is this sentnce correct?

> I can’t wait until the summer holidays have begun.

If not when can we use present perfect with until
thanks in advance

Comment: What do you think? Is it correct or incorrect? And why?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the numerous errors in punctuation and formatting  shows a distinct lack of care and effort.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the sentence is grammatically correct. It refers to a future time when the holidays have already begun. Then, my waiting will be over.

Comment: Well, yes. But I'm sure you don''t need to follow this NGram link for [***wait until it has begun / wait until it begins***](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=wait+until+it+has+begun%2Cwait+until+it+begins&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cwait%20until%20it%20begins%3B%2Cc0) to know which form is more ***likely***.

Comment: ...I found just 2 instances of [***wait until it has begun***](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22wait+until+it+has+begun%22) in Google Books. (It's *English*, but only just! :)

Comment: @FFRM, that is a very particular phrase. If you could include all instances of  other things than "it", and other verbs than "wait", there would likely be many more instances. The OP's expression would be less common than "begins", but it's a valid sentence representing a particular perspective.

Comment: True. But the OP's *specific* construction was too long for me to do that kind of "relative prevalence" reality check. And although I couldn't absolutely rule out a native speaker using that exact form, my immediate assumption on seeing just the written version would always be "non-native Anglophone".